# Exporting to quicktime in linux version?

Tags: export, animation, linux

In *MMA* (8.0.0/Linux), I tried to to create an animation using the command

```
Export["s4s5mov.mov", listOfFigures]
```

and got the output

[image]

Doing a little research, one can [read](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/format/QuickTime.html) in the Documentation Center that

[image]

And I was wondering **if there is some way to overcome this limitation *within MMA***.

**EDIT**

Here is a sample code of the inverted animation problem:

```
movingP = Table[Show[
    ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, AxesLabel -> {x, y}],
    Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
         Point[{Sin[(n \[Pi])/8], Cos[(n \[Pi])/8]}]}]
    ], {n, 0, 15}]

Export["~/Desktop/point.avi", movingP]
```

will produce an avi like this:

[image]

(The gif has been tampered to look like the avi)

Comment: You could `Export` to avi and then use ffmpeg (outside Mathematica) to convert to quicktime.

Comment: @b.gatessucks For some reason, when I export to avi, the image gets flipped upside down and left to right.

Comment: If you post some code I'll have a look from home.

Comment: As far as I know, Mathematica relies on the presence of a Quicktime installation to handle video output. Systems on which Quicktime isn't available won't work. I believe, but don't know for sure, there's no official Quicktime for Linux.

Comment: ¡ǝƃuɐɹʇs ʎllɐǝɹ s,ʇı

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries So, no hack can be cooked up then?

Comment: Export to BMPs and stitch together using VirtualDub would be an option.

Comment: @Pragabhava Ubuntu 10.04 and Mathematica 8.0.4 and the avi-export works fine. I tried mplayer and totem to play the movie.

Comment: @belisarius Which Linux and which version of Mathematica are you using?

Comment: @halirutan I'm using _MMA_ 8.0.0 in Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Lets wait for @belisarius. Maybe it's a bug in the 8.0.0 version. See my hack around this issue.

Comment: @halirutan Following your initiative, I opened the avi in VLC and it showed up just fine. This leads me to believe that the bug is in mplayer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One can export to AVI (for instance) and then use 3-rd party software (for instance, [ffmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/)) to do the conversion to MOV.
The following runs fine (without inversions) and the result can be viewed with mplayer, vlc:

```
Export["/tmp/point.avi", movingP]

Run["! ffmpeg -i /tmp/point.avi /tmp/point.mov"]
```

Comment: I'm accepting this post as answer since it solves the problem of producing the qt _within_ _MMA_, but thanks to ragfield and halirutan, the first one for clarifying why it's not possible to do it without third party software, and the second for providing a nice hack _for my mplayer_.

Answer (score 3):

Mathematica uses Apple's QuickTime library to create QuickTime movie files on Mac and Windows.  This library is not available (and never has been) for Linux.  You should be able to export to AVI or SWF and then perhaps use some 3rd party utility to perform a conversion if necessary.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious hack around the flipped movie is the use `ImageReflect` to correct each frame before the export

```
movingP = Table[
  ImageReflect[Rasterize[
    Show[ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], Cos[x]}, {x, 0, 2 \[Pi]}, 
      AxesLabel -> {x, y}], 
     Graphics[{Red, PointSize[Large], 
       Point[{Sin[(n \[Pi])/8], Cos[(n \[Pi])/8]}]}]], "Image"], 
   Top], {n, 0, 15}];

Export["~/Desktop/point.avi", movingP]
```

As a side-note: Since `Rasterize` creates the final raster image for the frame, all settings like image size or resolution have to be made their. In the `Export` call they won't work as expected anymore.